# C# DLL register failed QrCoder.dll

Tags: c#, windows, winforms, dll

Happy new year.
I’m using C# windows form to generate QcBarCode. But when I moved the application on the client machine I received this error

[image]

I have moved the DLL file to system32 and syswow64 but still not working .
When I run Regsvr32 I received

[image]

Comment: You are using setup file or using exe from bin folder?

Comment: I'm using exe bin folder

Comment: You might be using a different version of dll or not using dll.
Also if you using exe from bin folder then you have to use the entire output folder to run exe (only if you are using additional dll).

Comment: thank you, it works, I didn't replace the right app.config